# R convert sf object back to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, sf

How do I convert an sf object back to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

I am running R 3.4.0 and sf version 0.4.1. The [sf documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf) mentions an `as_Spatial` function, but this isn't available in my install (for some reason).

Comment: The coersion method is avalible at sf 0.4-1, what hapens when you try to call the function?

Comment: as(sf, "Spatial")

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans, Kazuhito's answer below replicates the problem (and provides a partial solition)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I used

```
 as(nc, 'Spatial')
```

as [part 2 of the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html) by Edzer Pebesma indicated (Scroll to the bottom of the page).

Comment: saw it. However I figured this out only recently and I felt the urge to put it into a proper answer when seeing this question ;)

Comment: And it is important the accepted answer will not be overlooked by future readers.

Comment: For this to truly work like a SPDF, I needed to do something like: `tmp <-as(nc, 'Spatial')`, then `tmpid <- sapply(slot(tmp, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))` then `row.names(tmp) <- tmpid`

Comment: what does 'truly work like a SPDF' mean? I see no disadvantage created by the conversion.

Answer (score 14):

I had to use `sf:::as_Spatial()` as workaround.

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# sf -> sp
nc_sp <- as_Spatial(nc$geom)      # Error: could not find function "as_Spatial"

nc_sp <- sf:::as_Spatial(nc$geom) # This works

library(sp)
plot(nc_sp)
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the dataframe intact?

Comment: Running `as(sf, "Spatial")` by @mdsumner , I confirm it produces SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, which is better for your requirement. It seems `as_Spatial()` takes sfc (ie geometry) only.

Comment: This function is a method and is ment to be call using as(). It is not exported as a function object which is why, to call it directly, you need ":::".

Comment: it seems the as() function is no longer in the `sf` package

Comment: ```as_Spatial(nc)``` will keep the dataframe intact!